# Maximum likelihood function - plot

Tags: r

Im doing some maximum likelihood in R. I have a dataset c(3,33,12,22,23) which corresponds to how long time a battery will last. The time a battery will last is Exp(theta) distributed. Im supposed to plot the Maximum likelihood function. I have this:

```
liklihood <- function(theta, n){
rpois(theta,n)
}

ac <- c(3,33,12,22,23)


theta <- seq(from=0, to=30, length=10)
plot(theta, liklihood(theta, n=length(ac)), type="l",xlab=expression(theta), 
ylab=expression(L(theta)), col="blue",
main="1 (b)")
```

but it does not look right, can anyone please help we if you see what I do incorrect.

Comment: by the way, it's not the "maximum likelihood function", it's just the "likelihood function".  The "maximum likelihood estimate" is the set of parameters that corresponds to the maximum of the likelihood function ...

Answer (score 1):

You should check the definition of the likelihood. Likelihood is product of densities of random sample and it is function of parameter. Your function `liklihood` samples (which is wrong) from Poisson distribution with probably wrong parameters - check `?rpois` (first parameter is sample size and second is lambda).

For Poisson distribution:

```
likelihood <- function(theta, x) prod(dpois(x, theta))
log_likelihood <- function(theta, x) sum(log(dpois(x, theta)))
```

Now you want to calculate likelihood for different values of theta keeping vector `x` same (in your case that is vector `ac`):

```
theta <- seq(0, 30, by = 0.5)
plot(theta, unlist(lapply(theta, likelihood, x = ac)))
```

[image]

For exponential distribution change `dpois` with `dexp` but be aware that mean of exponential is 1/rate.

Answer (score 0):

```
liklihood1 <- function(theta, x){ 
prod(dexp(n, 1/theta)) 
}
ac <- c(3,33,12,22,23) 

theta <- seq(0, 100, by = 1) 
plot(theta, unlist(lapply(theta, liklihood1, x = 
ac)),type="l",xlab=expression(theta), ylab=expression(L(theta)), 
col="blue", main="1 (b)")
```

is this correct for an exponential distribution?

Comment: put `theta` not `1/theta` for rate. And you don't need to go to 100 in `seq`. Type `?dexp` and in `Details` section you can see distribution.

Comment: but if dont put 1/theta i will just get at vertical line..

Comment: Use smaller range for theta `theta <- seq(0.001, 3, by = 0.05)`.

Comment: the values seem the get very samll

Comment: small values of what? Small values of theta -> mean is big because mean of exponential distribution is 1/theta.